# WebKit vs QtWebKit as an embedded browser

Tags: browser, webkit, qtwebkit

I need an embedded browser in an application. I am thinking of either using WebKit and call it via some API or use QtWebKit.

I do not understand the difference between QtWebKit and WebKit.

does QtWebKit put some UI i.e. frame/window on top on WebKit?

I see that PhantomJS uses QtWebKit when it is being built.

Is there a way to use Chromium as an embedded browser?

Answer (score 2):

Qt provides a cross platform UI framework similar to platform specific MFC (Windows). QtWebkit is Qt's port of WebKit web browser engine. This will mean that you will *easily* be able to use WebKit's functionality inside a Qt UI application which usually relies on signal/slot mechanism.

QtWebkit embeds Webkit and provides easy to use APIs for your application with the QWebView [class](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebview.html). **So, I suggest you use QWebView** for browser functionality in your application. If interested integration internals, a `QWebView::setUrl` call, will fall through `QWebView` -> `QWebPage` -> `QWebFrame` -> `QWebFrameAdapter` to reach WebCore which is core renderer of `WebKit`. You can see that at `QtWebkit` [github repo](https://github.com/qtproject/qtwebkit/blob/v5.4.0-rc1/Source/WebKit/qt/WebCoreSupport/QWebFrameAdapter.cpp#L170).

**Pros**

1. Integrating QtWebkit is far easier  compared to directly integrating `WebKit` into your application. Unlike QWebView APIs, there will be no easy to use API's with WebKit. In addition you have to really familiar with WebKit for direction integration. Also note that WebKit project doesn't have releases. Only nightly builds, from which you have to choose from.
2. Also with QWebView, you will not have handles cases like drawing
   combo box drop downs which WebKit leaves to the embedding
   application.

**Cons**

1. Using QtWebkit, you will not get latest Webkit functionality as
   it is released. You will have to wait it's port to QtWebkit.

You can use Qt's **QtWebEngine** [class](http://qt-project.org/wiki/QtWebEngine) for using Chromium as embedded browser

Comment: Thanks, It seems that it is difficult to use webkit directly or chromium directly , almost all embedded versions of webkit uses qtwebkit